# How can I achieve a node that will desaturate everything below it?

Tags: sprite-kit, shader, grayscale, sklightnode

I am building a game where everything behind the player is greyed out as if it lives in a memory. But I don't know how I can achieve this effect. Is this where shaders are being used for?

Now I can create a SKLightNode to create the lighting and make it dark around the edges. But I like to field of view for the character to be 120 degrees. Everything outside of that angle should be greyed out.

Of course in the future I like the view to be blocked by obstacles but that is outside of the scope of this question.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you take a look to this project? https://github.com/ymc-thzi/iOS8-SKLightNode

Comment: Yes it tells something about lightning but it doesn't say anything about desaturating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A desaturation shader for SpriteKit can be found at my [blog post](http://www.modejong.com/blog/post19_spritekit_bw_shader) on that subject. Note that this works in terms of an input texture, so you may need to adapt things to work on top of a tiled background. Also note that there is a new iOS 9 API to support capture of the output of a whole node, which may be useful to you in implementing this.